# Is there a way to prevent the bad formatting of auto-generated Repro Steps in VSTS

Tags: testing, azure-devops

Using the web browser test runner in VSTS and creating bugs from the runner.
It automatically inserts the Repro steps into the Bug but the formatting is very poor; see image. Is there a workaround to make the columns wider?

[image]

Comment: Which browser did you use? I cannot reproduce this issue with IE and Chrome.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue too. What's the detail version of your browser? Could you reproduce this issue with other browser?